# Famou.us event capturing performance

Tags: events, famo.us

Famo.us gives a more smooth user interface interaction than a gui coded with HTML elements directly, considering animations, scrolling etc.

Is Famo.us better at capturing the physical user input events like tapping, clicking?

Comment: How can one gain information from outside? 1. Reading, 2.Experimenting, 3. Asking to someone who can know. I have done 1st one and cannot find a convincing answer, SO is not the place for the 2nd one which I have not come here for , 3rd is what I have happened to do eventually after all.

Comment: The simple answer to this question is `NO`.

Comment: Better you write in the answer field not to the comment field.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not sure it adds any real value to just say that it does not improve performance on events, seams like shooting fish in a barrel. :)

Comment: better than drinking all the water in the barrel to catch the fish in it. Far more better than drinking the all water in the barrel to catch the fish in the sea. :). By the way the negative commenter's comment has gone but the down vote did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Famo.us` does not improve upon the event performance, but does have an `EventHandler` to allow for the sending of custom events along with core events in the DOM to elements created by `Famo.us`.

**[Here is some information about events in FAMO.US](http://famo.us/guides/events)**